# AMQP acknowledgement mule

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp

I'm having issues with the AMQP Connector in Mule ESB. When I send an request-response message inside my flow, initiated by an AMQP Inbound Endpoint. When I acknowledge the message I get an error about the inbound property 'delivery-key' missing.

I've tried setting and outbound property and sending that through a VM endpoint to another flow where it became and inbound property. However this didn't work.

I am using RabbitMQ.

Comment: Configuration, Mule and AMQP connector version please.

Comment: Are you saying that you are performing the acknowledgement in another flow, connected to the flow where the AMQP inbound is located with a VM queue?

Comment: AMQP connector: 3.3.0.2013061111625 From MuleStudio Cloud Connectors Update Site. I've got the latest version of the mule studio and version 3.4.0 of the server. What configuration information would you like?

Comment: Flow is as follows: Message comes in from the message bus, it's routed to an appropriate flow (according to a "routing-key" in the header of the message). There I reference two different flows which gets information from two different SOAP services and joins the responses together as JSON. Then the message is then sent to another queue on the Message Bus and the message is acknowledged.

Comment: Mkay, so I'm going to assume this means there are VM queues between the AMQP inbound endpoint and the flows where the acknowledgement happens.

Comment: We'll I'd rather not use the VM endpoints but that was a workaround I tried, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMQP message acknowledgement requires both a channel and a delivery key. Because channel is not serializable, it is stored in a flow variable (invocation-scoped message property) to prevent problems with serialization needs to occur at some point of the message processing (for example when using persisted VM queues).

With the version of the connector you are using, the delivery key is only stored in an inbound message properties. As explained [in this ticket](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/issues/18), inbound message properties are wiped-out when you use an outbound-endpoint amid flow (as you do with your `https:outbound-endpoint`).

You have two options:

- Build the [mule-3.3.x branch of the AMQP transport](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/tree/mule-3.3.x) to get the remediation (delivery key stored in a flow variable),
- Use a `message-enricher` to wrap your SOAP call in order to isolate it from the main flow so it won't wreak havoc in the inbound properties,

Comment: Ah, but I use flow-refs only. The VM queue I mentioned was only a workaround to get the "routing-key". I stored the routing-key in a flow variable and then set it as an outbound property after the external SOAP calls so it'd be an inbound property.

Comment: Show you're config, I'm completely lost.

Comment: [config](https://gist.github.com/365viktoralex/6083920), I've simplified it a bit by only calling one of the SOAP services but there will be two calls to SOAP services for now I'm mocking the second service. This is without the VM queues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check it out tomorrow.